# What's wrong with this Google Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically I'm trying to evaluate 9 different statements and find the smallest absolute value of them. Then, I want to return the NON absolute value of the statement back into the cell. This is meant to be expanded across cells. So my input for this is `=getCorrectedRotation(E5:5,F5:5,F14:14)`

I'm getting a #REF error. Any ideas?

```
function getCorrectedRotation(previous, current, step) {
  var r=0,s=0,t=0,u=0,v=0,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0
  var points = step.length;
  var output = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < points; i++) {
   r = ((current[i]-previous[i])/step[i])
   s = (((current[i]+360)-previous[i])/step[i])
   t = (((current[i]-360)-previous[i])/step[i])
   u = (((current[i]+360)-(previous[i]+360))/step[i])
   v = (((current[i]+360)-(previous[i]-360))/step[i])
   w = (((current[i]-360)-(previous[i]+360))/step[i])
   x = (((current[i]-360)-(previous[i]-360))/step[i])
   y = ((current[i]-(previous[i]+360))/step[i])
   z = ((current[i]-(previous[i]-360))/step[i])
  switch (Math.min(Math.abs(r),Math.abs(s),Math.abs(t),Math.abs(u),Math.abs(v),Math.abs(w),Math.abs(x),Math.abs(y),Math.abs(z))) {
    case Math.abs(r):
      output.push(r);
      break;
    case Math.abs(s):
      output.push(s);
      break;
    case Math.abs(t):
      output.push(t);
      break;
    case Math.abs(u):
      output.push(u);
      break;
    case Math.abs(v):
      output.push(v);
      break;
    case Math.abs(w):
      output.push(w);
      break;
    case Math.abs(x):
      output.push(x);
      break;
    case Math.abs(y):
      output.push(y);
      break;
    case Math.abs(z):
      output.push(z);
      break;
  }
}
  return output;
}
```

Comment: Here's a link to the spreadsheet btw. I'm trying to call the function in F12. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19zfc7XAgDbg6hVIybsOldKNsX5pt0DIQPetk7I-0QaA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like your reference error is probably the JavaScript equivalent of Java's ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error. I'd try changing

```
var points = step.length;
```

to

```
var points = step.length-1;
```

and see if that fixes your problem, as most "length" parameters are the number of elements (i.e. the maximum reference +1). As is, you're probably just referencing the "last point", which doesn't exist as it's outside the array.

Comment: Nope. Didn't change anything :( It had this problem even before I added that